# What tools to use to generate service code from schemas (svcutil analogue), if they do not meet the DataContractSerializer requirements

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl, code-generation, svcutil.exe

We are working on SOA, both on client (Silverlight) and server (WCF) sides, but with possibility of the clients being implemented by 3rd parties (.NET, Java, etc.). We use WSDL-first approach and want our data and services interface classes (C#) to be automatically generated from schemas during build process. So we need common data classes code not being regenerated for every service for successful compilation.

I have tried the **svcutil** utility, trying to first create all data contract classes from XSDs with the /dataContractOnly switch, and compile them to separate class library - *the first stage*. And then to create each service interface code, omitting the classes already in the library, with the /reference switch - *the second stage*.

The problem is that our schemas do not meet the DataContractSerializer requirements, so svcutil cannot create data classes. Even after I used **xsd** utility for this purpose, I cannot use svcutil's /reference switch on the second stage, since this switch only works for DataContract classes. And this is not the case with the classes generated by xsd utility.

So, am I missing something with these tools and are there any way to use them in my situation, or are there any other tools to generate data classes and service interfaces from XSD and WSDL schemas, in case where common data types are used by several service interfaces? Or should we hardly limit ourselves with DataContract compatible schemas? What approach do you use for WSDL-first development?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [WCF.blue tool](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/) by codeplex?
*WSCF.blue is a toolset that facilitates the development of web services using a contract first (specifically, a schema first) approach. This is the WCF version of the orginal Web Services Contract First tool.*

Also, there is a beautiful article on Contract-First development:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx

Comment: Thanks amit! I'll give the WSCF.blue toolset a try and write here my results. Thanks also for the link to the article, it was useful.

Comment: As far as I understand, WSCF.blue does not support command line interface and cannot be used to generate code automatically during build process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes WSCF.Blue is a VS plugin as it ships but the source is available and so it can be rebuilt into a command line interface version like what we had to do, with little effort required I might add.